# What does the "yy" in lex.yy.c stand for?

Tags: lex, flex-lexer

What does the "yy" in lex.yy.c stand for?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Lex was meant to be used in concert with Yacc.  The history and details of this are detailed in Steven Johnson's paper *[Yacc: Yet Another Compiler Compiler](http://www.scribd.com/doc/13625097/yacc)*.  The Yacc parser uses only names beginning in "yy' - there's no apparent meaning discussed beyond simply desiring a namespace.  The "yy" in lex.yy.c indicates that the lex output is intended for a yacc parser.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "yy" is used to indicate that this is a generated code file.

> Usually, the lex utility writes the program it generates to the file lex.yy.c
>   - [Reference](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xcu/lex.html)

Answer (score 1):

Probably from YACC (Yet Another Compiler Compiler), which was used with Lex to implement quite a few compilers and similar programs.  The Gnu equivalents are Bison and Flex, and look a lot more widespread now, so the connection may not be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes from Yacc, one of the older parser generators.